# Conditional row and column-wise replace of strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Given the following df:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'0' : ['find expert model','NR','R','NR'],
               '1' : ["news recommend", "NR" ,"NR", "NR"],
               '2' : ["a recommend", "R" , "NR", "NR"],
               '3' : ["a web recommend", "R", "NR", "R"]})
df_test

    0                   1               2           3
0   find expert model   news recommend  a recommend a web recommend
1   NR                  NR              R           R
2   R                   NR              NR          NR
3   NR                  NR              NR          R
```

I am trying to obtain this form of the df:

```
    0                   1               2           3
0   NR                  NR              a recommend a web recommend
1   find expert model   NR              NR          NR
2   NR                  NR              NR          a web recommend
```

The goal here is to replace every string `R` in a certain cell with the string from the first row of the distinct column. The replacing process should begin at the row with index 1.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you be more explicit in what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using `apply`, `replace`, and `drop`:

```
df_test.apply(lambda x: x.replace('R', x.iloc[0])).drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
                   0   1            2                3
0                 NR  NR  a recommend  a web recommend
1  find expert model  NR           NR               NR
2                 NR  NR           NR  a web recommend
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col] == 'R', col] = df.loc[0, col]
df = df.drop(0)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Results in:

```
                   0               1            2                3
0                 NR              NR  a recommend  a web recommend
1  find expert model              NR           NR               NR
2                 NR              NR           NR  a web recommend
```